# Adding and Updating observables in a part of the ViewModel with Knockout Mapping plugin - Not working

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Though this might look like many of the similar questions about knockout mapping plugin and partial view model updation, I did not see the issue im facing here reported in all my searching.

I will detail with an example below but in short this is what I am trying to do.

**First** I create View Model from a Javascript Object using KO Mapping plugin's `ko.mapping.fromJS`.
Now I want to update only a part of the view model with the data that I receive from the server. So.

1. I convert the viewModel to a JavaScript object using `ko.mapping.toJS`
2. Update the part of the JS object with the data from server
3. Use the updated JS object to update the view model using `ko.mapping.fromJS`

**The problems**

1. Values of observables when first created from JS object through mapping remain the same even after update
2. If new properties are present in the server data object, they show-up with the values they
   came with, in the updated view model  - but then will not update to new values in consequent updates.

Here is a simplified example.

**The View**

```
<div>
  <label data-bind="text: mainTitle"></label>
  <div data-bind="with: layer0">
    <label>Name - </label>
    <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
    <label>Type - </label>
    <label data-bind="text: type"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Data model which will be used to make the ViewModel

```
  var dataModel =  {
     mainTitle: "Main Title",
     layer0:{
              itemDetails:{
                            name:"item1name",
                            type:"type1"
                          },
              otherDetails:{
                             prop1: "prop1Value",
                             prop2: "prop2Value"
                           }
    }
```

This JS object `dataModel`  is converted to KO View Model by

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(dataModel);
```

and applied to the view above by applyBindings and it displays data as expected

Now I receive this JS object from the server

```
var newJSobjectFromServer =  {
         name: "item2Name",
         description: "item2Description"   // new property that was not on first model
         type: "type2"
        }
```

Now I cannot do

```
viewModel.layer0.itemDetails(newJSobjectFromServer);
```

because in the `viewModel` which was created by the mapping plugin `itemDetails` is a property and not a method only `name` and `type` are methods

So I first extract a JS object from the viewModel by

```
var viewModelJS = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);
```

Then I update a part of the `viewModelJS` with new server data

```
viewModelJS.layer0.itemDetails = newJSobjectFromServer;
```

so `viewModelJS` becomes

```
{
 mainTitle: "Main Title",
 layer0:{
          itemDetails:{
                       name: "item2Name",
                       description: "item2Description"   // new property 
                       type: "type2"
                      }, 
          otherDetails:{ 
                         prop1: "prop1Value",
                         prop2: "prop2Value"
                       }
        }
}
```

Then I try to update the viewModel by

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJS , viewModel);
```

also tried

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModelJS , {}, viewModel);
```

but the result is

`layer0.itemDetails.name()` is still `"item1"` and `layer0.itemDetails.type()` is still `"type1"` while the new observable `layer0.itemDetails.description()` is present and has the value "item2Description"

now if I repeat the updating with another server returned object

```
{
   name: "item3Name",
   description: "item3Desctiption" 
   type: "type3"
}
```

this time all the values in `viewModel` remain same as last time that is 
`layer0.itemDetails.name()` is still `"item1"` and `layer0.itemDetails.type()` is still `"type1"` and
`layer0.itemDetails.description()` is still `"item2Description"` and thus nothing changes in the view.

The complexities of the objects handled make it necessary for me to use the mapping plugin only the example is simplified but does completely portray the problem I am facing. I am really reaching out for someone to guide me how to get that part of the viewModel updated with the data from the server in the above exact scenario. If that is solved I can apply it to the more complex real world scenario that I am facing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your UI is still bound to the same ViewModel and running the mapping again doesn't refresh it.

You can use a different approach where you create a parent view model and set your "viewModel" as an observable member of the parent ViewModel. Check out this fiddle for a very rushed (but working) example of this behavior

http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/4SKNd/2/

```
var parentViewModel = function (data) {
    var _self = this;
    _self.Data = ko.observable('');
    _self.LoadData = function () {
        _self.Data(new viewModel(data));
    };
    _self.GetNewData = function (data, item) {
        _self.Data(new viewModel(newJSobjectFromServer));
    };
    _self.LoadData();
};
var viewModel = function (data) {
    var _self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, _self);
    _self.Data = ko.observable(data);
};
ko.applyBindings(new parentViewModel(dataModel));
```

Also, if the GetNewData() function makes an ajax call to get the data, this will still refresh your UI - that's how I use this "pattern."

**UPDATE**

Some ideas: 1) restructure your data so it's uniform in all cases. Otherwise you'll be building each of the viewModels very differently which is just going to cause readability headaches later. 
http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/Q5RRr/1/

2) If you can't restructure the data, ditch the mapping plugin and do everything manually. I'd say this yields much cleaner markup and gives you more control of the data. 
http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/5DD27/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion 
Well there are a few hurdles in the real-world case which I think I was not able to get across. 

I forked your fiddle.

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/mike_freeman/TnuG4/5/)

1) The very first view model itself needs to be construed from a JS object - though injecting a child view model might be possible

2) Note the object returned from the server is not the whole structure

3)Most importantly as seen in the fiddle other elements referring to the $root or $parent exist among the element bound by context to itemDetails so will a child viewmodel still work.

Comment: See my update. You may want to forego the mapping plugin on this one